# Get all td values of a table that have a certain class with DataTable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I found this code on [DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()) page.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.column(0).data().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log('Data in index: ' + index + ' is: ' + value);
});
```

This code show all values of all td of first column. But, in my table, td can have different class. So, I want to take only values of td that have, for example, the "a" class.

```
<td class="a"> Hello </td>
<td class="a"> Hi </td>
<td class="b"> By</td>
<td class="b"> How are you?</td>
<td class="a"> Hello world! </td>
```

The code will return `Hello, Hi, Hello world!`

It's possible?

**UPDATE:**

My code:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="b">Hello</td>
            <td class="b">World</td>                              
            <td class="a">346.387,81</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="b">Hello</td>
            <td class="b">World</td>                              
            <td class="a">444.392,35</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share fiddle for same??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`cells()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29) API to filter based on class name:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.cells('.a').data().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log('Data in index: ' + index + ' is: ' + value);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gv6nrq4/)**

If you want to limit it to a certain column index, you can pass that as a second parameter to `cells()`, e.g.:

```
table.cells('.a', 2).data().each(...);
```